# Replace date pattern

Tags: regex, replace, filenames, file-rename

I am trying to remove the dates from file names. The below works when I put in an actual date (i.e. 2017-05-05), but I am trying to generalize it for anything that matches this pattern `\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d`. It gives no error, but no file name changes. I think my format is wrong. I have tried several different instances, but can't get it to work.

```
$source = c:\path\to\folder
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $source )
{Rename-Item $file $file.name.Replace("\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d","")}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which language are you using? Most likely, `\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b` will work as well.

Comment: @Jan Powershell.. unfortunately that doesn't work either.. what am i missing.. aaahhh

Comment: You need `- replace`, the`.Replace` replaces literal strings.

Comment: your regex should be working, Jan's looks like a better version.  The bug must be elsewhere.  Try just stripping out a hard-coded number to test.

Comment: @sniperd I tried it with `Rename-Item -Newname {$file.name -replace "\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d",""}` and it worked.. i believe @ Wiktor Stribiżew was right